# Weird issue using addFieldToFilter via a helper method

Tags: collection, helper

I've got a really strange situation ! I'm new to magento, but this is looking really weird, hope anyone can help me with that !

Here is the controller action I have :

```
public function searchSpecialOpeningsAction(){  
            $shops = Mage::getModel("shops/shops")
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter("status", 'open')
                ->addFieldToFilter('type', array('eq' => 'ok'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('opening_special', array('neq' => ''))
                ->setOrder('name', 'asc');
            $shops2 = Mage::helper('shops')->getSpecialOpenings();

//            Mage::log('before_shops1-'.$shops->count());
//            Mage::log('before_shops2-'.$shops2->count());

            $dates = Mage::helper('shops')->getSpecialOpeningsDates();
            $shops->addFieldToFilter(array('postcode','city'), array(array("like" => trim($search)."%"), array("like" => "%".trim($search)."%")));
            $shops2->addFieldToFilter(array('postcode','city'), array(array("like" => trim($search)."%"), array("like" => "%".trim($search)."%")));

            Mage::log('sql1-'.$shops->getSelect()->__toString());
            Mage::log('sql2-'.$shops->getSelect()->__toString());

            Mage::log('after_shops1-'.$shops->count());
            Mage::log('after_shops2-'.$shops2->count());
}
```

And here is Mage::helper('shops')->getSpecialOpeningsDates();

```
public function getSpecialOpenings($sort_field = 'name', $sort_dir = 'ASC')
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel("shops/shops")
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter("status", "open")
            ->addFieldToFilter('type', array('eq' => 'ok'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('opening_special', array('neq' => ''))
            ->setOrder($sort_field, $sort_dir);
        ;

        if(count($collection) > 0) {
            return $collection;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

As you can see $shops in the action is just the content of getSpecialOpenings method from the helper.
When $search = "06", "after_shop" should be equal to 0 but here is the output :

```
2014-04-03T15:04:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): sql1-SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `shops` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = 'open') AND (type = 'ok') AND (opening_special != '') AND ((postcode LIKE '06%') OR (city LIKE '%06%'))
2014-04-03T15:04:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): sql2-SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `shops` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = 'open') AND (type = 'ok') AND (opening_special != '') AND ((postcode LIKE '06%') OR (city LIKE '%06%')) ORDER BY name ASC
2014-04-03T15:04:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): after_shops1-0
2014-04-03T15:04:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): after_shops2-2
```

Why the order clause is present on sql2 but not on sql1 ?
Why when I use my method "after_shop" = 2 and when I use the content of my method "after_shop" = 0 !?

I've got also another really weird issue when i decomment the 2 log lines, watch the input :

```
2014-04-03T15:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): before_shops1-2
2014-04-03T15:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): before_shops2-2
2014-04-03T15:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): sql1-SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `shops` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = 'open') AND (type = 'ok') AND (opening_special != '') AND ((postcode LIKE '06%') OR (city LIKE '%06%')) ORDER BY name ASC
2014-04-03T15:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): sql2-SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `shops` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = 'open') AND (type = 'ok') AND (opening_special != '') AND ((postcode LIKE '06%') OR (city LIKE '%06%')) ORDER BY name ASC
2014-04-03T15:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): after_shops1-2
2014-04-03T15:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): after_shops2-2
```

"after_shops1" value becomes 0, but i've just decommented 2 log lines, why it would affect the code !? And you can see that the order clause is now present on both select.

I guess the order clause is affecting the result but first why ? and why in one case it is addded to the select and not on the other case ? plus why decommenting log lines are affecting the execution ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `count()` calls `$collection->count()` which does:

```
\Varien_Data_Collection::count
public function count()
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

and after the collection is loaded you can do whataver `addFieldTo*` but it isn't used anymore. So remove the `if(count($collection) > 0)` and everything is fine :-) Or instead use `getSize()` which does not load the collection:

```
\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSize
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```